# How to resolve a 'notice: array to string conversion' error using foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to show 10 questions options using `PHP` and `MySQL`, and show each question options using `foreach` loop, but I get a notice.

I have 2 tables named "questions" and "options" and I have a field in options named `q_id` which has joined question table by id field.

This is my SQL code:

```
public function selectOptions($id)
{
    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("select options.option1,options.option2,options.option3,options.option4 FROM `options` INNER JOIN questions ON options.q_id = questions.id WHERE questions.id = '$id'");
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //var_dump($row);die;
    return $row;
}
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
foreach ($num as $key => $value) {
    $toal[] = $num[$key]->id;//this will be the questions id
}

$q_id = $toal;

foreach ($q_id as $val) {
    $j =$obj->selectOptions($q_id);//this will select options
    var_dump($j);
}
```

I expect the output to be an array of options but it returns an error:

> notice : array to string conversion

How can I resolve the above issue?

Comment: its in the first part

Answer (score 3):

You sending the wrong argument to the function as you sending `$q_id` (the original array) and not `$val`.

Your code say:

```
foreach ($q_id as $val) {
    $j =$obj->selectOptions($q_id); // you use the $q_id which is array
```

The `selectOptions` is treating its argument as string and not array therefor the notice.

Change your code to:

```
foreach ($q_id as $val) {
    $j =$obj->selectOptions($val);
```